# Android broadcastreceiver static registering problems

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, registering

I understand that I can register a broadcast receiver either statically through the manifest or programmatically by registering and unregistering the receiver in an activity.  In my case I want the OS to instantiate and call my broadcast receiver when my code is not in memory.  So I included my receiver in my manifest.  Unfortunately if my code is not in memory, my broadcast receiver never runs.  I am very confused as to why this is.  I have included snippets of my manifest below.  Please let me know if there is something wrong/missing with this.  Thank you.

```
<receiver android:name=".DesktopConnectionReceiver" 
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Delete `android:process=":remote"` and try again.